# await する必要がない場合に「Task を返す」のと「await + ConfigureAwait(false) を使う」のはどちらが良いでしょうか

Tags: c#

ライブラリの中で非同期メソッドを呼ぶときは、`ConfigureAwait(false)` を使用してデッドロックを回避する、と多くのサイトで書かれています。
次のように待つ必要がない場合に関しても、`ConfigureAwait(false)` を使用するべきなのでしょうか？
もちろん処理の内容によるとは思うのですが、判断の指針となるものがあれば教えていただきたいです。

```
public static Task<HttpResponseMessage> PatchAsync(this HttpClient client, Uri requestUri, HttpContent content, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var method = new HttpMethod("PATCH");
    var request = new HttpRequestMessage(method, requestUri) { Content = content };

    return client.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

自己解決しました。

同様の質問がありました。
[Return Task or await and ConfigureAwait(false)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23536848/return-task-or-await-and-configureawaitfalse)

これを踏まえて、私は次のように実装しようと思います。

- 非同期メソッドの後に処理が必要なら `async Task` メソッドにする。必要なければ `Task` メソッドにする。
- `async Task` メソッドにする場合は、`await` する非同期メソッドを `ConfigureAwait(false)` する。
- `async Task` メソッドか `Task` メソッドかで、例外の伝播が変わることに留意する。

  - `async Task`：メソッドを待機したタイミングで例外が発生する。
  - `Task`：メソッドを呼び出したタイミングで例外が発生する。

---

例外の発生タイミングについての補足です。
次のメソッドを呼び出す場合を考えます。

```
public static async Task With(int millisecondsDelay)
{
    await Task.Delay(millisecondsDelay).ConfigureAwait(false);
}

public static Task Without(int millisecondsDelay)
{
    return Task.Delay(millisecondsDelay);
}
```

直列で呼び出す場合は、同じ場所で例外が発生します。ただし、スタックトレースは異なります。

```
// (1) With 直列
try
{
    await With(10);
    await With(-2); // ここで例外が発生
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex);
}

// (2) Without 直列
try
{
    await Without(10);
    await Without(-2); // ここで例外が発生
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex);
}
```

並列で呼び出す場合は、違う場所で例外が発生します。

```
// (3) With 並列
try
{
    var task1 = With(10);
    var task2 = With(-2);
    await Task.WhenAll(task1, task2); // ここで例外が発生
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex);
}

// (4) Without 並列
try
{
    var task1 = Without(10);
    var task2 = Without(-2); // ここで例外が発生
    await Task.WhenAll(task1, task2);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex);
}
```

[async／awaitで例外処理をするには？［C#／VB］](http://www.atmarkit.co.jp/ait/articles/1805/16/news018.html)の「複数のタスクを並列実行したとき、発生した全ての例外を知るには？」で紹介されている方法では (4) の場合に対応できないため、(3) と (4) 両方に対応できるように次のようにするのが良さそうです。

```
var all = null as Task;
try
{
    var task1 = With(-10);
    var task2 = With(-2);
    all = Task.WhenAll(task1, task2);
    await all;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex);
    if (all != null)
    {
        foreach (var innerEx in all.Exception.InnerExceptions)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"[InnerExceptions]");
            Console.WriteLine(innerEx);
        }
    }
}
```